# Nuxt3 Data Fetching - How does it work under the hood?

Tags: nuxtjs3, nuxt3

I've been using vue3 for a while and am trying to migrate to Nuxt3. I am running into an issue regarding data fetching.

### Background

In my vue app, I have a `useGet` hook that basically wraps an API call. It checks cache and if the cache is empty, it calls a server to fetch the data. This `useGet` is a very generic function and sets a bunch of default values like the base url, so that I can make smaller resource specific hooks like `useJobs` which calls the `useGet` hook with a specific endpoint. This enables me to call `const jobs = useJobs();` in my components, so I only have to specify the paths once and only need one line to get the data.

### Issue

I am trying to recreate this setup, so I can access the jobs in a similar way. However, no matter how I spin it, on initial page load (after a `ctrl/cmd + r`) the value of the jobs is an HTML string. See screenshot

[image: Screenshot of what console.log(jobs.data.value) is on page load.]

After I change something in the code and hit save, it actually loads the data correctly. See screenshot

[image: Data correctly loaded after HMR]

Now I understand that this probably has to do with the serialisation of the data, but what I expect to happen is that once the data gets loaded on the server, I am able to iterate through it, and render some HTML based on in. And subsequently, the clientside should not do anything with it. Because I want this data to be rendered server side, so I can actually reap the benefits of SSR.

### Code I tried:

Directly inline:

```
const config = useRuntimeConfig();
const { data: jobs } = await useFetch('/jobs/', {
  baseURL: config.public.API_URL,
});
```

Using abstraction

```
// useApi.ts
import { useFetch } from 'nuxt/app';

const useApi = () => {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()


  const get: typeof useFetch = (url, params) => {
    return useFetch(url, {
      params,
      baseURL: config.public.API_URL,
      key: url.toString(),
    });
  };

  return { get };
};

export default useApi;

// component.vue
const { get } = useApi();
const { data: jobs } = await get<IJob[]>('/jobs/');
```

If anyone can explain to me why Nuxt doesn't handle SSR data fetching and subsequently rendering it serverside before sending it to the client, I would be super happy. I cannot understand why this does not work intuitively.